# Rolling a formula from one column to the next in a table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to roll a formula across 39 columns. Since this is very time consuming, I was hoping to use VBA. Essentially, what I want is something like this:

```
=SUM(A1:B1)     =SUM(A1:C1)   =SUM(A1:D1)
```

but need to have the formula roll across 31 columns.

Thank you for anyone's help.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Please Help Me" Not a Real Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Also take a [tour] of SO and read [ask] to understand how we work and can help you the most here. It's a great resource if you help us help you.

Answer (score 4):

Put:

```
=SUM($A1:B1)
```

in the first cell and drag over.  The `$` will lock the column on the first reference, while the other will change.

Comment: How would this be written in VBA? I'm asking because the formula is more complex then the sum example I provided and I am using it in a table so the table columns would be referenced in the formula instead of cell references.

Comment: @MatthewLee - it's best to ask the question you really want answered: if you "simplify" then all that happens is we end up answering two questions...

Comment: @MatthewLee there is no way to answer that, as with vba I would still leverage the `$` and drag method to fill the formula.  So without seeing your more complex formula, there is no way to answer that.

Comment: @ScottCraner The formula I'm using is the following: =IFNA(INDEX(Base2[HTS (6 Digit)],MATCH(0,IF([@[General Description]]=Base2[General Description],COUNTIF(Table3[@[HTS 1]:[HTS 2]],Base2[HTS (6 Digit)]),""),0)),"")  while needing the countif(Table3[HTS 1]:[HTS 2]) to change to countif(Table3[HTS 1]:[HTS 3]) in the next column  and so on. I hope this provides more detail as this is the most time consuming issue I have ever encountered.

Comment: use indirect: `COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Table3[[HTS 1]:[HTS " & COLUMN(B:B) & "]]"),"")` and when it is copied over it will increase the 2 to 3 to 4 to ... @MatthewLee

Answer (score 1):

Enter in B2 and drag:

```
=SUM($A$1:B1)
```